# Copy a dynamic set of range in one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code that will open a several csv workbooks (let's call this "Source file") listed in "RefData" sheet then copy its contents to destination file.

I have this code working but I'm not really impressed by how it is coded. I believe there's is much better way.

```
Private Sub OpenDL()

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim wrk As Workbook
    Dim this As Workbook
    lastrow = Sheets("RefData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wrk = ThisWorkbook
    Sheets("RefData").Select

For i = 1 To lastrow

    'open workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).Value).Select

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "HistoricalPrices_" & Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).Value & ".csv"

    'copy Date, Open, High, Low, Close & Volume
    Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wrk.Activate
    Sheets(Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).Value).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    'close csv file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks("HistoricalPrices_" & Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).Value & ".csv").Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next i


End Sub
```

The way how I code it is something like this:

1. based from the list in refdata column A, macro will open the source
   file. the macro have to select A1 up to F + lastrow.

**Screenshot of RefData sheet**

[image]

2. Then it will copy it.
3. next is it will close the source file.
4. paste it to the destination file, in its correct sheet. Please note
   that each item listed in Refdata column have its own sheet.
5. the macro ends.

My issue here is there an easy way to eliminate the step 2 and 3 where it will manually select the ranges then copy it?

I have an idea, not sure if its possible. it goes something like this:

```
sourcefile.sheets(sheets("refdata").cells(i,1).value).range("A1:F" & lastrow of the destination file).value **=** destinationfile.activesheets.range("A1:F" & lastrow of the destination file).value
```

something like:

the value of destination file > Sheet(Refdata).cells(I,1) > Range(A1 to F(x) **is equal to the value of the** Source File > activesheet > Range A1 to F(x)

where x = last row of the source file?

I'm not sure if this is possible. Any help is appreciated

Comment: 'copy Date, Open, High, Low, Close & Volume                                                                                                       how about this:                                                                                                       
        Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).Copy Destination:= wrk.Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).Value).Paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wsDest.Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).value = wsOrgn.Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).value
```

However, you need to declare and set the `wsDest` (Destination worksheet) and `wsOrgn` (Origin worksheet). You can start with:

```
Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsOrgn As Worksheet
```

and set the `Worksheet` based on the flow of the process:

```
'before you open the source, set the destination first
Set wsDest = wrk.Sheets(Sheets("RefData").Cells(i, 1).value)

'codes
'...

'once the source file opened and active on the sheet.
Set wsOrgn = ActiveSheet
'Transfer info from source to destination sheet
wsDest.Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).value = wsOrgn.Range("A1:" & Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Address).value
```

`Range` can be more precise by getting the last row from the origin and use it on both `wsDest` and `wsOrgn`.

P.S. Those PSE Stocks tho LOL.

Comment: Thank you kulapo for your help! It worked perfectly. and yes, those are PSE Stocks. :D